# Need help creating subdirectories to store files with dates in them

Tags: command-line, bash

New to this forum, however not new to RHEL or scripting. However this one is a bit annoying me. I have the following files:

```
2019-05-01-00.34.00.msg 
2019-05-02-00.36.00.msg
2019-06-14-01.38.00.msg
```

I want to store them in directories like this:

```
/2019/05/01/<Filename>
/2019/05/02/<Filename>
/2019/06/14/<Filename>
```

I would like to keep the current file name as well when placing them in the directories. Also, I would like to do this with bash.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Well I don't think they should be created under `/`. A better idea would be `/home/user/messages/2019/05/...`

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/546977/108618)

Comment: @David Lashua Are you using Red Hat? Their site is http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Here are three files,

```
$ ls
2019-05-01-00.34.00.msg  2019-05-02-00.36.00.msg  2019-06-14-01.38.00.msg
```

Use the following one liner in your terminal,

```
$ for i in *.msg;do mkdir -p $(awk -F- '{print $1"/"$2"/"$3}' <<< $i) && mv $i $(awk -F- '{print $1"/"$2"/"$3"/"$0}' <<< $i); done
```

Next, see the tree,

```
$ tree
.
└── 2019
    ├── 05
    │   ├── 01
    │   │   └── 2019-05-01-00.34.00.msg
    │   └── 02
    │       └── 2019-05-02-00.36.00.msg
    └── 06
        └── 14
            └── 2019-06-14-01.38.00.msg

6 directories, 3 files
```